# AppStore metadata not localized

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

My app's primary language is English and is localized for Vietnamese.

On itunesconnect, I created metadata in Vietnamese. In the "Rights and Pricing", I selected all territories.

My friend from Vietnam opened my app on the AppStore and sees English instead of Vietnamese. Why is this happening?

I opened "Version History" link on iTunesConnect and changed territory dropdown list from "United States" to "Vietnamese" the metadata stays in English, nothing changed.

UPDATE: The image below captured from a AppStore on a live product. Under "Languages" row, both English and Vietnamese are listed, but my friend from Vietnam region cannot see the localized description.
[image]

Does anyone know why I'm not getting the metadata localized? Thanks.

Comment: On iTunes connect there is an option to write everything in localised language. So basically you need to set description and images in both (English and Vietnamese) language on iTunes connect. Its nothing to do with store.

Comment: My app description is in both English and Vietnamese. The images are shared between both language.  However, my friend in Vietnam isn't seeing the description in Vietnamese.